# How do I read this text file and Insert into MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, text-files

sample

```
user id  User Name
   U456      Mathew 
   U457      Leon
   U458      Cris
   U459      Yancy
   U460      Jane
```

and so on up to 500k.

I need to read this text file and insert to MySQL  in two columns say User ID and User Name. How do I do this in PHP?

Answer (score 8):

[LOAD DATA INFILE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html)

Example:

NOTE: if you run this from Windows you need to escape the forward slashes in the file path.

EXAMPLE:

```
C:\\path\to\file.txt
```

Looks like:

```
C:\\\\path\\to\\file.txt
```

Here is the query:

```
LOAD DATA INFILE '/path/to/sample.txt' 
INTO TABLE `database_name`.`table_name` 
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'
IGNORE 1 LINES
(
user_id, user_name
)
```

Answer (score 4):

Delete the first line and use this command

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'C:\\sample.txt' 
INTO TABLE Users 
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ' '  
LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n';
```

For more information visit
http://tech-gupshup.blogspot.com/2010/04/loading-data-in-mysql-table-from-text.html

Answer (score 2):

Using PHP, Possibly Something similar to this:

```
$file = "/path/to/text/file.txt";
$fp = fopen($file, "r");
$data = fread($fp, filesize($file));
fclose($fp);
```

The above reads the text file into a variable

```
$output = explode("\n", $output);
foreach($output as $var) {
$tmp = explode("|", $var);
$userId = $tmp[0];
$userName = $tmp[1];
```

Tell it to explode at each Endline and then store the data in temp variables

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO table SET userId='$userId', userName='$userName'";
mysql_query($sql);
```

Execute the query for each line

Answer (score 0):

Depends. If the two fields are separated using a TAB character, then `fgetcsv($f,1000,"\t")` would work to read in each line. Otherwise use `substr()` if it's a fixed width column text file to split up the fields (apply `trim()` eventually).

Loop over the rows and fields, and use your database interface of choice:

```
db("INSERT INTO tbl (user_id, user_name) VALUES (?,?)", $row);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the fopen function of PHP to access and read the file.. From there on the rest is pretty much simple. Read the file line by line and insert the values into the database.

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php

The above link gives a very good description of how the fopen function works.. Using a loop will be easy in this task.