# Insert data from text file to MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql, import, text-files

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I read this text file and Insert into MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4729031/how-do-i-read-this-text-file-and-insert-into-mysql)

I need to import this text file into MySQL. The field names are written at the top of the file.

```
SEDOL^DESCRIPTION^VALUE
B02W0Y2^EUROSTAR LTD^35.09^^
B02V64S^NORTHERN ROCK^21.97^^
B06N3Q2^MOTOR OIL SAPA^7.24^^
B05WF50^COLT TELECOM GROUP^20.29^^
B03R2SA^XEROX CAPITAL^35.65^^
B09G3SD^COREALCREDIT^12.10^^
B04F5GD^ULSTER BK LTD^16.46^^
B02DH5H^EUROTUNNEL FINANCE^53.24^^
B05D3WK^BRADFORD & BINGLEY^18.07^^
B05DGEF^SKIPTON LTD^4.50^^
B07DHX4^EBAY INC^46.55^^
B08VEW1^FURSTENBG CAP^86.36^^
B06HS34^LBG CAPITAL^54.22^^
```

Can anybody give some ideas on how to achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```
LOAD DATA INFILE '<filepath>' INTO TABLE <tablename>
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '^'  LINES TERMINATED BY '^^\r\n';
```

Comment: I think you actually need `LINES TERMINATED BY '^^\r\n'` or MySQL will think there are more data fields than columns. Of course the OP would also need to delete the first line.

Comment: @MikeBrant why should he remove the first line? IGNORE number LINES

Comment: MySql will read it like it's a row

Comment: @iroegbu adding IGNORE 1 LINES will - surprisingly - ignore one row from top - the first - row ;o)

Comment: @SirRufo You are correct `IGNORE [number] LINES` would work fine.

Comment: :) interesting stuff... Thanks a lot!

Comment: `^^` ... looks ugly ... +1