# php insert data from text file to mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I have a text file logfile.txt:

```
2013-01-01 12:01:00    ip:11223344    region:    country:US    bandwidth:123
2013-01-01 12:01:55    ip:22222    region:    country:UK    bandwidth:123
2013-01-01 12:03:12    ip:34566    region:    country:US    bandwidth:123
2013-01-01 12:07:08    ip:123123    region:    country:US    bandwidth:123
```

How can I insert it to mysql, with these columns:

```
ID        |    IP_client    |    country    |    bandwidth
```

Comment: use explode() first explode with spaces and than with :

Comment: is it CSV ?? give some more details about file

Comment: Possibly duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4729031/how-do-i-read-this-text-file-and-insert-into-mysql

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$text = file_get_contents('file.txt');
$text = explode("\n",$text);
foreach($text as $line)
{
$temp = explode('ip:',$line);
$ip = explode(" ",$temp[1]);

$temp = explode('country:',$line);
$country = explode(" ",$temp[1]);

$temp = explode('bandwidth:',$line);
$bandwidth = explode(" ",$temp[1]);


$sql = "INSERT INTO MY_TABLE (IP_client,country,bandwidth) VALUES ('".$ip[0]."','".$country[0]."','".$bandwidth[0]."')";
mysql_query($sql);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use the similar code, its a tab separator:

```
$data = file_get_contents("file.txt");
 $convert = explode("\n", $data); //create array separate by new line
for ($i=0;$i<count($convert);$i++)
{
  //insert record here
}
```